# Is Feldspar likely to occur near iron ores, next to them, or mixed with them?

Tags: geology

As the question probably shows, I am not really versed in geological sciences, but it is rather a worldbuilding question I have regarding a setting based on the North Carolina area of the USA. Would a mining town be able to extract feldspar without going too far away from any iron deposits, or would the two of them be separated enough to make the effort of establishing a settlement to mine one or the other viable?

As always, apologies if the question or its format is not welcome in the forum and thanks in advance for any answer.